# How to display LWJGL window and swing window at same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, lwjgl, display

I want to do the following:
I've got a LWJGL display, and a running game loop. I did not explicitly create a thread for this. It just runs on the thread it takes. (the thread it is created in?)
Now I want to create a Swing JFrame, but of course this is not that simple.
Because when I tried this, the swing window blocks. It just doesn't update and it won't close, and this behaviour is expected.
I tried to create a new thread and put the JFrame in that new thread, but also this doesn't change the behavior.
I really know swing should be executed in the Event Dispatch Thread, but I don't know how to solve this problem. I also tried a lot with `SwingUtils.invokeLater`, but actually this has very little to do with the problem.

What can I do to have a LWJGL display and a working JFrame at the same time?
I want that JFrame to display generated BufferedImages to debug. The BufferedImages are used for creating textures. I don't want to output that debugging data to disk, and just want to display the images in a JFrame.

Comment: Swing uses it's own thread so it should work fine when you `invokeLater` the code that creates the frame like in this example (see main method, there is 0 code that touches swing things outside the invoked `createAndShowGUI` method): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FrameDemoProject/src/components/FrameDemo.java - hard to tell what you do wrong without knowing your code.

Comment: I didn't call all my swing code from `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, I changed it now, and the frame updates now and doesn't block anymore. But it only shows up when the lwjgl display closes. So how to solve that?